# Allow only specific no of digits using jquery

Tags: jquery

My requirement is i have a textbox which should accept 18 digits if 18 digits is done it should automatically add a dot and after dot it should aacept only 2 digits that is two decimals
i.e 123456789123456789.98
or 12345678.44
or 1234567891234.22

like this before dot it should take less than or equal to 18 and after dot only two

Below is the code which i tried which is not working as expected

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Regular Expression to Validate Decimal(18,2)</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ValidateDecimal() {
            var value = document.getElementById('txtValue').value;
            var regex = /^[0-9]{0,18}(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/;
            if (!regex.test(value)) {
                document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].style.display = "block";
                return false;
            } else {
                document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>
    <input name="txtValue" type="text" id="txtValue" onkeyup="ValidateDecimal()" />
    <span style="display: none; color: Red;">Invalid</span>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: so the user can input a dot as long as the digits are < 18 and if they're = 18 a dot is added automatically by the script ?

Comment: try inputmask [LINK](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask)

Comment: yes exactly ths

Comment: @deepa123menon, Please check this link also https://jsfiddle.net/yacmed/5mspcxog/

Comment: @deepa123menon, if you want without plugin please check this one also https://jsfiddle.net/mykisscool/VpNMA/

Comment: @jishan siddique  i cant use input mask i need to do it using regular expression in jquery

Comment: @jishansiddique my requirent is completely different please check my question

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.number').keypress(function(event) {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ((event.which != 46 || $this.val().indexOf('.') != -1) &&
    ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) &&
      (event.which != 0 && event.which != 8))) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  var text = $(this).val();
  if (text.length === 18) {
    $(this).val(text + ".")
  }
  if ((event.which == 46) && (text.indexOf('.') == -1)) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      if ($this.val().substring($this.val().indexOf('.')).length > 3) {
        $this.val($this.val().substring(0, $this.val().indexOf('.') + 3));
      }
    }, 1);
  }

  if ((text.indexOf('.') != -1) &&
    (text.substring(text.indexOf('.')).length > 2) &&
    (event.which != 0 && event.which != 8) &&
    ($(this)[0].selectionStart >= text.length - 2)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" class="number" maxlength="21" />
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this **@Vishal**, i only edited the `maskedformat` to suit your needs.

```
$('body').on('keyup', '.maskedExt', function () {
    var num = $(this).attr("maskedFormat").toString().split(',');
    var regex = new RegExp("^\\d{0," + num[0] + "}(\\.\\d{0," + num[1] + "})?$");
    if (!regex.test(this.value)) {
        this.value = this.value.substring(0, this.value.length - 1);
    }
});
```

Comment: i cant use mask i should using jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can see if the `input`'s length is 18 and we didn't yet received a dot then automatically add one and after that do the regex check as usual.

```js
const inp = document.getElementById("txtValue"),
  span = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];

function ValidateDecimal() {
  const regex = /^[0-9]{0,18}(?:\.[0-9]{0,2})?$/; /** \.[0-9]{0,2} now we accept a number that ends with a dot thus no error is shown **/
  inp.value.indexOf('.') === -1 && inp.value.length === 18 && (inp.value += '.'); /** add a dot ONLY if there's no dot and the length is 18 **/
  span.style.display = !regex.test(inp.value) ? 'block' : 'none'; /** regex check **/
}
```

```css
/** just for demo purposes **/
input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input name="txtValue" type="text" id="txtValue" onkeyup="ValidateDecimal()" />
<span style="display: none; color: Red;">Invalid</span>
```

> BTW no need for `jQuery`.

Comment: @deepa123menon it's logic to have a message after the dot as it's not a well formed number (11. is not a number so a message is shown). Do you want to hide the message even if the number ends with a dot ?

Comment: yes no need of message it should satisfy the below cases

1) if i have given less than 18 digits before decimal i should be able to add (.) manually and after (.) it should all only 2 no's
2) if it is equal to 18 then (.) should be populated automatically and after (.) it should all only 2 no's

Comment: @deepa123menon How ? What's the problem ?

Comment: @deepa123menon but it accepts one or two numbers after the dot !

Comment: more than 2 but i need only one or 2 after dot which is of user interest

Comment: @deepa123menon it is working as your needs. Try to reload the page by pressing `CTRL + F5`.

Comment: @deepa123menon check this [pen](https://codepen.io/Thabet_Sakhraoui/pen/abbxNWa).

Comment: @deepa123menon but it accepts only one or two digits after the dot ! What is the problem ?

Comment: for me the updated code is not coming i think it is accepting multiple numbers after decimal

Comment: const inp = document.getElementById("txtValue"),
  span = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];functionValidateDecimal() {
  const regex = /^[0-9]{0,18}(?:\.[0-9]{0,2})?$/; /** \.[0-9]{0,2} now we accept a number that ends with a dot thus no error is shown **/
  inp.value.indexOf('.') === -1 && inp.value.length === 18 && (inp.value += '.'); 
  span.style.display = !regex.test(inp.value) ? 'block' : 'none'; 
} <input name="txtValue" type="text" id="txtValue" onkeyup="ValidateDecimal()" />
<span style="display: none; color: Red;">Invalid</span> input {display: block;width: 100%;}

Comment: this is the code  i could see i dont need message to show just enough not to allow anything if conditions met

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202850/discussion-between-ths-and-deepa123-menon).